# How can I get the list of all the warning messages at one place in vs2012

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, error-handling

I have a collections of projects in c# .net project. I want list of all the warnings messages while debugging vs2012 at one place not in individual pages. Is there any plugin or tool for that in vs2012 professional.

Please note that i need the list of warning messages not the error messages. If there is some third party tool except the inbuilt tool which gives help in removing the warning please do mention that also in the answer. The main concern is list of all warnings so that i can remove them with better approach.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, as the "Error List" window does show all the errors, and warnings for the current solution in one place?

Answer (score 0):

Anything wrong with the built-in Error List (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33df3b7a.aspx)?

Comment: I checked this post but i think the output window shows warning messages of only current document not all the project. I have multiple projects inside current current .net project and i need list of all the warnings so that i can resolve them fast and with better approach.

Comment: I does show all warnings, but only when the assembly is compiled. So when you hit 'Build' and there are no changes to the code files, it hides the warnings for that project.

Comment: Is there any third party tool for managing warnings and managing them in better approach. Like little more help topics related to warnings or something like that.

Comment: What do you want to do with it? There are several options, but then we need to know more about what you want to achieve.

Comment: Any questions or errors left? If not, please mark as answered.

Answer (score -1):

If you have to perform exception-dangerous action for each collection element, then:

1. Instantiate `List<Exception>`.
2. Loop a collection with `foreach`.
3. Place `try catch` block in cycle for each operation.
4. When an error occurs, put the `Exception` in `List<Exception>` and proceed.
5. When ended, construct `AggregateException` with `List<Exception>` and rethrow

All of this is made with the following sample:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ExceptionsSample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void PerformUnsafeActionsWithCollection()
        {
            //ExceptionsList
            var allErrors = new List<Exception>();
            //Collection
            var integersArray = new int[16];
            //Cycle
            foreach (int i in integersArray)
            {
                try
                {
                    //Throws an exception (division by zero)
                    Decimal result = Decimal.Divide(i, 0);
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    allErrors.Add(exception);
                }
            }
            if (allErrors.Count > 0) throw new AggregateException(allErrors);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                PerformUnsafeActionsWithCollection();
            }
            catch(AggregateException aggregateException)
            {
                foreach(Exception error in aggregateException.InnerExceptions)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error occured: {0}", error.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice code, but not an answer to the question. The question is about compile time, not run time.